# Is there a maximum number of vertices that can be drawn by an AMD GPU in OpenGL 3.3?

Tags: c++, opengl, point-cloud-library, glm-math, point-clouds

I have written a small application to display large pointclouds of vertices of usual size ~ 20m points consisting of position values xyz and colour values RGB.

I experianced no issues on a workstation with a Nvidia GTX 670 GPU but have now changed to another workstation with a AMD HD6950 and now large pointclouds are not being displayed.

I originally thought that there might be a limit to the number of vertices that the AMD GPU can draw in a single call but after additional testing think that this is not the case.

I generated a test pointcloud (done with simple 'for' loops) larger then the other point clouds and with the same format [vc3(xyz) & vec3(rgb)] and this cloud still displays but not the other large pointcloud from the laser scanner.
Looking at the VBO states in CodeXL these are all present and of the correct size (233MB for 20m vec3's) so i cannot see where the error might be unless the non-debug pointcloud is obtaining incorrect values from somewhere.

It's also worth noting that I have used small pointclouds (30k vertices) and they load fine but not the large ones on the AMD computer.

As a sanity check this is the code for generating the debug pointcloud:

```
// Holders for position and colour
std::vector<glm::vec3> t_position;
std::vector<glm::vec3> t_colour;

// Reserve memory
t_position.reserve(point_cloud_size);
t_colour.reserve(point_cloud_size);

// Generate Data
for (int x=0; x < cube_root; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < cube_root; y++) {
        for (int z=0; z < cube_root; z++) {
            t_position.push_back(glm::vec3(x/10.0 - 0.5, y/10.0 -0.5, z/10.0 -0.5));
            t_colour.push_back(glm::vec3((float)x/10.0,(float)y/10.0,(float)z/10.0));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the method for generating the laserscanner pointcloud:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>::Ptr pointcloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>);

if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile(point_cloud_path, *pointcloud) == -1) // Loading pointcloud from file path.
{
// Error Catch
    PCL_ERROR("Could not load pointcloud\n");
}

// Number of points in cloud
point_cloud_size = pointcloud->size();

// Sanity Check
std::cout << "Loaded Pointcloud of size: " << point_cloud_size << std::endl;

// Create data vectors
std::vector<glm::vec3> t_position;
std::vector<glm::vec3> t_colour;

// Reserve space in vectors for data
t_position.reserve(point_cloud_size);
t_colour.reserve(point_cloud_size);

// pointer for pcl data
pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal point_ptr;

std::cout << "Converting Pointcloud into vectors" << std::endl;
// Convert pointcloud to individual components (NEEDS OPTIMIZING)
for (int i = 0; i<point_cloud_size; i++) {

// Loading Bar for point cloud conversion
    loadbar(i, point_cloud_size);

    point_ptr = pointcloud->at(i);

    t_position.push_back(glm::vec3(point_ptr.x, point_ptr.y, point_ptr.z));
    t_colour.push_back(glm::vec3(point_ptr.r/255.0, point_ptr.g/255.0, point_ptr.b/255.0));
}
```

Both pointclouds are loaded to VBO's and VAO's with the same method:

```
BindPointCloud(t_position,t_colour);
```

So I cannot see the binding being the issue.

So I am pretty lost as to what the problem could be as it works fine on a workstation with a NVidia GPU but not an AMD one.

Any advice?

Comment: Pixel fill rate is about 20-30 Gp/s, triangle rate is about 2 Gt/s.

Comment: What happens when you scale the number of vertices by the same factor that the available video memory has been scaled?

Comment: So, 10m points with X, Y, Z data in "float" will be 120GB, so I doubt that this in itself leads to an out of memory situation. HOwever, if you have, say > 100m data items, I could see how it would be an "out of memory" simply from the vertices. However, graphics memory needs more than just vertex data, so depending on what textures and other data your model is using, it's possible that 2GB graphics memory simply isn't enough to hold all the data at once. Are you checking carefully for error situations, and if so, what error messages do you get?

Comment: I should add that my experience from having worked with graphics processors/graphics code in various places, it is unlikely that there is a fixed limit. It is very likely that your code is simply doing something that "the hardware is unable to deal with", rather than "You can't use more than X vertices" in a call.

Comment: 10 million points stored using 32-bit floating-point <X,Y,Z> = 114.44 MiB, not 120 GB. That said, since AMD literally invented OpenGL debug output, you might consider using `ARB_debug_output`. AMD is pretty verbose and there will probably be a warning explaining if you are doing something fundamentally wrong, but not wrong enough to generate an API error.

Comment: I tried some additional debugging on this using AMD's CodeXL and have edited the original post accordingly.

Comment: DX11 maximum vertices theoretically is 128mb of vertex data and 10^32 vertices, accordin to:  MSDN Resource Limits (Direct3D 11) page.  So that's in dx11, OpenGL should have some resource limits specifications somewhere, same as dx11?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was with the pointclouds coordinates.

There was a strange transformation being applied to the pointclouds so that they were not being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AMD's own tools, [gDEBugger](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/gDEBugger/) is a good tool for this.

Comment: Thanks I used AMD's CodeXL to try and get a better understanding of what was going on in the shader.